# SharePoint doesn't index BDC integers?

Tags: bdc

I'm having the same problem described [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgenerallegacy/thread/18822069-c981-4e16-8287-bd304deddc04/).  I can search on all sorts of strings returned by my BDC connector, but any data that is returned as Int32 doesn't show up in searches.  Is there a problem with the model xml?  Is this a known shortcoming of SP or BDC?  What other data types does this apply to?

Of course I can `.ToString()` any numeric data, but I'm hoping for a more elegant solution.